# MiniZinc - What's the simplest example of `alternative` scheduling global predicate?

Tags: minizinc

I'm new to MiniZinc and the only examples I could find using `alternative` were rather complex and involved the use of other global predicates which makes it even more difficult to understand it.

```
predicate alternative(var opt int: s0,
                      var int: d0,
                      array [int] of var opt int: s,
                      array [int] of var int: d)
```

> Alternative constraint for optional tasks. The task with start time s0 and duration d0 spans the optional tasks with start times s[i] and durations d[i]), and at most one of those tasks can occur.

Source - https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.7.3/en/lib-globals-scheduling.html#mzn-globals-scheduling-alternative

What could be the simplest example of using `alternative` predicate? For what kind of tasks would one want to use it, for example?